# FILE, fopen etc... error. file is NULL

Tags: c, file, fopen

I am trying to read a file which is located at the same source as my .c code. I tried this little sketch and same problem. What could be wrong?
File's extension and name are just the same.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    char caracter;
    FILE *ARCHIVO;
    ARCHIVO=fopen("prueba.txt", "r");
    if (ARCHIVO==NULL){
        printf("Error·");
    }else{
        while (feof(ARCHIVO)==0){
            caracter=fgetc(ARCHIVO);
            printf("%c", caracter);
        }
    }
    fclose(ARCHIVO);
    return 0;
}
```

I will be very thankful if someone could help me. 
Regards.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: And avoid that use of feof. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: Instead of printf("Error.") write perror("prueba.txt") to get a better error message.

Comment: If you try a simple test such as `ARCHIVO=fopen("testprueba.txt", "w"); fclose(ARCHIVO);` is the file created at the location you expect? One thing you can do is to give `main` its full signature `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` and work out a folder name from `argv[0]` (the executable).

Comment: That seems to work. At least it doesn't show the error message. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Your file doesn't have the read permission thats why it is giving the error while.

Try the following :

```
chmod a+r prueba.txt
```

This will fix the problem. Hope so !!!